# How do I achieve this different div order and positioning for different screens (using bootstrap)?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a number of div elements that I want to organize as illustrated below. I'm using bootstrap 4 but can not figure out how to achieve that.
For the large display I want to specify a max width for A,B,C,D and E should use the rest. For the small display they should all use full width.

Optional: If possible I would like A,B,C,D to fit their content and specify min-width for E. If there is not enough space for E then the "small display" layout should be used.

[image: div positions]

Comment: I suspect this was closed due to the "optional" part? I feel the judgment might be a little hard here. As a bootstrap novice I'm not able to tell if the div width setting is an independent issue so I decided that it would be good to include a description of what I am actually trying to achieve in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use basic Bootstrap layout for desktop and for mobile (or any breakpoint you would like) you can use `flex` and `order` while using `display:contents`.

Attribute `order` which has `.order-X` classes in Bootstrap changes order of element inside of `flex`. Display `contents` removes element from the accessibility tree - so it makes parent `div` like it doesn't exist - and makes its children like they are directly in *flex* and *orderable*.

Something like this (output that matches your image):

```css
.d-contents {
   display: contents;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12 col-md-6 bg-success">
    A
  </div>
</div>
<div class="d-flex flex-column flex-md-row">
  <div class="col-12 col-md-6 px-0 d-contents d-md-block">
    <div class="bg-warning order-1">
      B
    </div>
    <div class="bg-info order-3">
      C
    </div>
    <div class="bg-danger order-4">
      D
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 col-md-6 px-0 d-contents d-md-block">
    <div class="bg-secondary h-100 order-2">
      E
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> **display: contents**
> Current implementations in most browsers will remove from the accessibility tree any element with a display value of contents (but descendants will remain). This will cause the element itself to no longer be announced by screen reading technology.
>
> Source: [display - CSS: Cascading Style Sheets | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display#display_contents)

This solution [won't work on Internet Explorer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display#browser_compatibility).

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap uses a 12 column layout. You can give each div multiple classes to define their width.

The col class has also the possibility to define the width on different media queries by adding for example col-md-12 for middle or col-xl-12 for large screens.

The full documentation is here:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/grid/

You have to try around with different values until the divs go in the order you want.

If that doesn't work you can use margin in you css combined with media queries.

Comment: The problem with that is that if I define them in order A-B-E-C-D then I think the top of C will be aligned with the bottom of E on the large display. And I also think that i might need an outer div for A,B,C,D to make them same width, so E doesn't really fit there.